# Wikitude Browser Control to separate nearest POI

Tags: augmented-reality

I am trying to display POI in Wikitude browser one below another which are overlapping one behind another in AR Browser.
When I am adding two poi with nearest location that POI on AR view showing one Behind another. so secondly added POI is not visible on AR view.

How can I fix that problem. I want to separate that POI so that both can be visible in Ar viewperate nearest POI